# Standard normal distribution Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In a standard normal distribution variable, what is the probability of obtaining a value greater than $-0.01$.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck. Our aim is to improve your mathematical skills. We are no calculators.

Comment: Hint: maybe symmetry can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick up a [standard normal distribution table](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/img/normal-table-large.png).

Then, you have $P(Z>-0.01) = P(Z<0.01)$ (due to the symmetry of the distribution).

So find the row with $0.0$ and the column with $0.01$ ($0.0 + 0.01 = 0.01$) and there's the result: $$0.504$$

Note: look up on the internet how to use these kind of tables. They are quite useful.